# How can I avoid DuplicateKeyException when updating a MongoDB document when it is not fetched from the DB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot appication (2.5.3) using a MongoDb and I want to update a document in this MongoDb which is already persisted.
Over my REST controller such documents can be updated, hence, the application creates the proper beans being used to update the documents. These objects/documents contain a composite ID which is annotated with `@Id` and they have a version property annotated with `@Version` as well. Hence, it is not a database generated ID!

Whenever I perform a `<myRepository>.save(...)` I get a DuplicateKeyException.

How can I succeed this way. I would prefer to not read operation before.

BeanA - abstract base class:

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@Validated
public abstract class BeanA {

    @Version
    private Long version;    // Needed to make @CreatedDate work during auditing.

    @CreatedDate
    private ZonedDateTime createdAt;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private ZonedDateTime modifiedAt;

    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String modifiedBy;
}
```

BeanB - concrete class:

```
@Data
@Validated
@SuperBuilder
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "BeanB")
public class BeanB extends BeanA {

    @Id
    private TheCompositeId compositeId;

}
```

CompundID class:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TheCompositeId {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 3)
    private String foo;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 2)
    private String bar;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 2)
    private String foobar;

}
```

All "entity" classes have equivalent DTOs to work upon in the application being mapped to the entity/document class when applying the repository.

The test excerpt from test class:

```
@Test
void shouldUpdate() throws Exception {
    // given
    var beanBApiModel = BeanBTestBuilder.aDefaultBeanBApiModel().build();
    var json = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(List.of(beanBApiModel));

    // when & then
    mvc.perform(post("/store").content(json).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());

    json = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(CompositeIdMapper.toCompositeId(beanBApiModel.getCompositeId()));

    ResultActions res = mvc.perform(get("/find").content(json).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());

    var beanBDoc = objectMapper.readValue(res.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString(), BeanB.class);
    beanBApiModel = BeanBMapper.toBeanBApiModel(beanBDoc);
    beanBApiModel.setModifiedBy("xxx");
    
    json = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(List.of(beanBApiModel));
    mvc.perform(put("/update").content(json).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());

    verify(beanBService).update(List.of(beanBApiModel));
}
```

Test class signature:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class BeanBControllerIntegrationTest extends AbstractMongoDbIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mvc;

    @SpyBean
    BeanBService beanBService;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    BeanBRepository beanBRepository;

    ...
}
```

The BeanBService simply invokes the base CRUD operations on the `MongoRepository`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have either to:

1. read the document from the database (in case the document was modified in the meantime by somenone else)
2. set the version property